# Selecting Collections not working in my nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my main app.js, where i start the mongodb connection to my mlab database

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./routes/db');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);

//routes
const users = require('./routes/users');

const url = 'mongodb://user:pw@url/dbname';

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/users', users);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('server');
});

app.use(express.static('../www'));

db.connect(() => {
    console.log(`mongodb connected!`);
});
```

The connection works, the console log gets triggered. Here's how my db.js looks like, which i import in my app.js to start the connection (using the connection() method):

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://user:pw@url/dbname';
let mongodb;

function connect(callback){
    mongo.connect(url, (err, db) => {
        mongodb = db;
        callback();
    });
}
function get(){
    return mongodb;
}

function close(){
    mongodb.close();
}

module.exports = {
    connect,
    get,
    close
};
```

Now in one of my routes i want to select a collection form the database and perform a query on it. This looks like the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const db = require('./db');


// Get user data
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {

    db.get().collection('users').findOne( {"id": userId}, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            if(data === null) {
                console.log('user doesnt exist');
            } else {
            res.json(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Again importing the db.js file to use the methods, using the database connection to perform the query. Now here i get the error:

"TypeError: db.get(...).collection is not a function"

And i don't know why this is not working. Can someone point out to me where i go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting this error on compile time ?

Comment: the error appears, when i try to call the API endpoint from the frontend to get the user data

Answer (score 0):

I think connect has not been initialized.Please try this code.I didnt checked it.

```
const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const mongodb = require('mongodb');
    const db = require('./db');


    // Get user data
    router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    db.connect(()=>{
    db.get().collection('users').findOne( {"id": userId}, (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                if(data === null) {
                    console.log('user doesnt exist');
                } else {
                res.json(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly does not work. Still same error